# How to link two custom taxonomies in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

Let's say I have one custom taxonomy called "movies" and another called "actors". How to I link those two taxonomies so as to know which actors play in such and such movie, or which movie does such and such actors plays in ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use tags or categories and make a custom loop.